# Using a Bidirectional Layer causes errror: CancelledError: [_Derived_]RecvAsync is cancelled

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am having an issue where whenever I include a Bidirectional Layer wrapper in my model, it causes a crash during training with the following error:

```
CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7944b517869f> in <module>
      1 history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10,
      2                     validation_data=test_dataset,
----> 3                     validation_steps=30)

D:\Python\anaconda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

D:\Python\anaconda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

D:\Python\anaconda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

D:\Python\anaconda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    805       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    806       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 807       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    808     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    809       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

D:\Python\anaconda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2827     with self._lock:
   2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 
   2831   @property

D:\Python\anaconda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
   1846                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))],
   1847         captured_inputs=self.captured_inputs,
-> 1848         cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1849 
   1850   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

D:\Python\anaconda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1922       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1923       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1924           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1925     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1926         args,

D:\Python\anaconda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    548               inputs=args,
    549               attrs=attrs,
--> 550               ctx=ctx)
    551         else:
    552           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

D:\Python\anaconda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

CancelledError:  [_Derived_]RecvAsync is cancelled.
     [[{{node gradient_tape/sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup/Reshape/_38}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5988]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I am running the exact code from the Tensorflow tutorial here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_classification_rnn#prepare_the_data_for_training.

Furthermore, I have tried including the lines
'''
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
'''
at the start of my program, and I get the same issue.

My Tensorflow version is 2.3.0, Cuda version is 10.1.243, and CUDNN version is 7.6.5.

Does anyone know a possible solution for this problem?

Comment: Downgrade to tensorflow v 1.14

Comment: Do you mean Tensorflow 1.14 or Tensorflow 2.1.14? I'm trying to learn how to use Tensorflow 2 specifically, so I would prefer not to downgrade if possible.

Comment: Okay. I meant 1.14. I had Tensorflow 2 , encountered the same problem , downgraded , problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

The above-mentioned [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_classification_rnn#prepare_the_data_for_training) is working fine for me using google colab.

Your Tensorflow version is compatible with Cuda and CUDNN version, that should not be an issue.

The issue could be the memory usage error and this should be solved by.

```
import os
os.environ["TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH"]="true"
```

Comment: Setting `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH ` to `true` did not resolve the issue for me when using GPU to train RNN on Kaggle.